# UWP no error but can not display my screen

Tags: win-universal-app

I am writing an uwp program, you may treat it as a drawing segments program:
It is only allow to draw segments horizontal or vertical.
a new segment must start at an old segment's vertex, and there are two situation not allowed in this program:
1.overlap.
2.intersection.

Here is my code to judge if two segments are cross over each other，Here is my code :

(I use a for loop to select all of segments I have already created, "line[]" stored all the segments I have already created and "ln" stored a random new segment, it will add the new segment to "line[]" if no erro occurs)

```
for (int l = 0; l < i - 1; l++)
{
    if (ln.getY1() == ln.getY()&&line[l].getX()==line[l].getX1())
    {
        if(line[l].getX()>=Math.Min(ln.getX(),ln.getX1())&&line[l].getX()<=Math.Max(ln.getX(), ln.getX1())&&ln.getY()>=Math.Min(line[l].getY(),line[l].getY1())&&ln.getY()<= Math.Max(line[l].getY(), line[l].getY1()))
        {
            sameIslandCount++;
        }
    }
    else if (ln.getX1() == ln.getX()&&line[l].getY()==line[l].getY1())
    {
       if(ln.getX()>=Math.Min(line[l].getX(),line[l].getX1())&&ln.getX()<=Math.Max(line[l].getX(), line[l].getX1())&&line[l].getY()>=Math.Min(ln.getY(),ln.getY1())&& line[l].getY() <= Math.Max(ln.getY(), ln.getY1()))
       {
            sameIslandCount++;
       }
    }
}
```

but when I test this program,  it stuck in this screen:
[image]

but if I delete all the equal symbol, the program can run successfully. Can anyone tell me how to improve? sorry about my English, hope you can understand what I mean:p

Comment: As it is, it's extremely difficult to understand or even help you with your problem. Particularly, the pasted code is of no use as it is (it may throw null pointers exceptions or true/false values everywhere). Please specify the problem and paste *all* the relevant code in a minimal example for us to be able to understand it.

Comment: sorry, code is too long, It is hard to paste it, but I have modified my question, the code I pasted is  for checking the new segment if it is cross over other segments that I already created. these judgement cause the problem, because when I delete "=" from my code, it can run successfully

Comment: Can you try to detect at which point does it hang? Stepping through the launching process could probably give you some hints.